# Why does Python unpacking operator work with unordered collections

Tags: python, python-3.x, sequence, argument-unpacking

The [Python 3 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) about the unpacking operator (`*`) generically speaks of a "list or tuple," while the error message for improper use says that a "sequence" is needed:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(a, b):
...     return a / b
...
>>> f(*1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

Python 3's [Built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) documentation lists the following sequence types:

- Sequence Types — `list`, `tuple`, `range`
- Text Sequence Type — `str`
- Binary Sequence Types — `bytes`, `bytearray`, `memoryview`

Quick test:

```
>>> all(isinstance(x, collections.Sequence) for x in [[], (), range(1), '', b''])
True
```

Note that set types (like `set` and `frozenset`) and mapping types (`dict`) are *not* included here.

```
>>> any(isinstance(x, collections.Sequence) for x in [set(), {}])
False
```

---

My question: **Why are all iterable types (including a `set` or `dict`) unpackable?** They are not sequence types, as the `TypeError` above suggests they should be, and unordered behavior leads to undefined results when unpacking for positional args:

```
>>> def f(a, b):
...     return a / b
...
>>> f(*{4, 2})
0.5
>>> f(*{8, 2})
4.0
>>> f(*{4:1, 2:1})
0.5
>>> f(*{2:1, 8:1})
4.0
```

Comment: Pretty sure only iterator methods are required for that. Unpacking predates abstract collection types.

Comment: The error message in Python 3.5 is `TypeError: foo() argument after * must be an iterable, not int`

Comment: So, basically you ask [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski No--my question is why unordered collections allow unpacking, given the error message and unexpected behavior with positional args. I understand that they are arbitrary.

Comment: Dict and set are not a sequences, but they are iterables (they implement iterator protocol). Since they are implementing it, there is absolutely no reason for them not to be able to unpack. Integers are not iterables, why would you expect them to unpack successfully?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I think you're misunderstanding OP's question. His question is asking why the raised TypeError uses the term "sequence" and not "iterable"

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Right: as it turns out, there is a bug in the error description I cited which was corrected in a future release.

Comment: I guess the issue with the error message is "solved", but something still doesn't feel completely right about being able to unpack *positional* arguments from an *unordered* collection. (No doubt this is why the error message originally mentioned *sequences*; as that would, at least naively, make the most sense. And maybe it was even true in very early versions of Python.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is most likely a little bug<sup>*</sup>. Anything that is an iterable is accepted during function calls; this is hidden inside the [section for Calls in the Python Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call, expression *must evaluate to an iterable*. Elements from these iterables are treated as if they were additional positional arguments.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

*Which, as of `3.5.2` as @sytech pointed out, was fixed in [`Issue 4806`](http://bugs.python.org/issue4806) to correspond to the correct wording in the reference manual.

Comment: A bug that, evidently, has been addressed. I'm on 3.5.2 and the message actually says ***iterable*** not *sequence*

Comment: @sytech Right, pointed that out, any luck finding that bug report yet?

Answer (score 4):

This is no longer the case in (at least) Python 3.5.2 -- Probably was recognized as an issue and changed in a version later than what you're using. The message now more appropriately reads ***iterable*** instead of *sequence*

See https://bugs.python.org/issue4806

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...     print(*args)
...
>>> foo(*1)
TypeError: foo() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

Comment: Interesting: I'm using v3.5.1:37a07cee5969

Comment: I'm on 3.5.2 -- specifically v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5